# Where does poisson distribution functional form come from?

Tags: probability-distributions, alternative-proof, poisson-distribution

I know that the punctual probability function of a random variable $X$ with a Poisson distribution is:

$$P(X=k)= e^{-\lambda }\frac{\lambda ^{k}}{k!}.$$

Also, I've learned that the formula can be found as a limit of the binomial distribution. However, I was wondering if there is another way to obtain the formula without using the binomial distribution. I guess that the $e^{-\lambda }$ is used to normalize the probability, but **I can't work out the idea behind the $\dfrac{\lambda ^{k}}{k!}$ part.**

Comment: You can also derive it from probability generating functions. Start with PGF of binomial, use the same limiting procedure to obtain a new PGF and use the properties of PGFs to recover the “newly” discovered PMF of the Poisson RV.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Wikipedia article [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution)

> the sum of two independent random variables is Poisson-distributed, then so are each of those two independent random variables

So assume $\ X_1\ $ is Poisson with parameter $\ \lambda_1\ $ and $\ X_2\ $ is Poisson with parameter $\ \lambda_2.\ $ Let $\ X_0 = X_1 + X_2\ $ be the sum of the two variables.
By definition of sum of random variables we have $\ \lambda_0 = \lambda_1+\lambda_2\ $ and $\ P(X_0 = 0) = P(X_1 = 0)P(X_2 = 0).\ $ Let
$\ f(\lambda_i) = P(X_i=0).\ $ Then $\ f(\lambda_1+\lambda_2) = f(\lambda_1)f(\lambda_2).\ $ This is a well-known [Cauchy functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy%27s_functional_equation) with solution 
$\ f(\lambda) = f(1)^\lambda.\ $ Next we look at the value of
$$ P(X_0 = 1) = F(X_1 = 0)P(X_2 = 1) + F(X_1 = 1)P(X_2 = 0). $$
Divide both sides by $\ P(X_0 = 0)\ $ to get
$$ P(X_0 = 1) / P(X_0 = 0) = P(X_2 = 1)/P(X_2 = 0) + P(X_1 = 0)/P(X_1 = 0). $$
If $\ f(\lambda_i) := P(X_i = 1) / P(X_i = 0),\ $ then this a well-known functional equation with solution $\ f(\lambda) = c\lambda.\ $

To continue, we should take advantage of the ordinary generating function of a random variable
$$ G_X(z) := \sum_{n=0}^\infty P(X = n)\ z^n. $$
The special property of this is that $\  G_{X+Y}(z) = G_X(z)G_Y(z).\ $ Thus
$\ G_{X_0}(z) = G_{X_1}(z)G_{X_2}(z).\ $
Let $\ G_{\lambda_i}(z) := G_{X_i}(z),\ $ then
 $$ G_{\lambda_0}(z) = G_{\lambda_1+\lambda_2}(z) = G_{\lambda_1}(z)G_{\lambda_2}(z). $$ This is the Cauchy equation again and the solutions to it  uniquely determine the Poisson distribution. More precisely,
$$ G_\lambda(z) = (\exp(z)/\exp(1))^\lambda = \exp (\lambda z)/\exp (\lambda)
= \sum_{n=0}^\infty = \exp(-\lambda) (\lambda\ z)^n/n!. $$
This now gives us the expected $\ P(X = n) = e^{-\lambda} \lambda^n/n!.$

Comment: So there are strong mathematical reasons why the Poisson distribution must have exactly this form.  But I am not aware of any modeling argument that leads to this distribution. It seems that some limit (or calculus) argument is always required. This is different from the binomial distribution, which can be derived with combinatorial arguments alone.

Comment: But proving the Poisson distribution by using two Poissons doesn't answer my question about the origin of the formula.

Answer (score 2):

To see that $X$ is a valid probability mass function note that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty P(X=k)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}=e^{-\lambda}\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}=e^{-\lambda}\times e^{\lambda}=1
$$
and obviously $P(X=k)\geq 0$.

As you also noted if $X_n\sim\text{Bin}(n, \lambda/n)$, then $X_n\stackrel{d}{\to } Y$ where $Y\sim \text{Poi}(\lambda).$

Another way is to use poisson processes/renewal processes. Let $X_i\stackrel{\text{i.i.d}} {\sim} \text{Exp}(1)$ be exponential random variables with mean one and put $T_n=X_{1}+\dotsb+X_n$ and put $N(t)=\max\{n\mid T_n\leq t\}$. Then we have the relation
$$
N(t)\geq n\iff T_n\leq t\tag{1}
$$
which allows us to compute $P(N(t)=k)$ as  the event $(N(t)=k)=(N(t)\geq k)\setminus (N(t)\geq {k+1})$ and we can use (1). It turns out that after some computation that $N(t)\sim \text{Poi}(t)$.